# How to merge 2 graphql schemas on client, to auto-generate types?

Tags: client, apollo, codegen, graphql-codegen

I have a client that queries 2 endpoints. Now, how do I auto-generate types from 2 graphql schemas, when using 2 endpoints?

Scripts I used up until now (with standard 1 endpoint) uses Apollo codegen ([source](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/tooling/apollo-codegen/typescript-graphql-code-generator-generate-graphql-types/)):

```
"schema": "npx apollo service:download --endpoint=http://localhost:8080/graphql graphql-schema.json",
"types": "npm run schema && apollo client:codegen --localSchemaFile=graphql-schema.json --variant=development --target=typescript --addTypename --queries=./src/**/*.graphql --useReadOnlyTypes --globalTypesFile=src/globalTypes.ts . && npm run prettier"
```

Possible solution is also generating 2 introspection schemas and then merging them together, I just didn't find how.

I'm also open to move to Graphql Code Generator.

Is there any example, guidance, or link please?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL Code Generator supports configuring multiple schemas by merging their definitions automatically for you.

You will find some documentation on this matter here: https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/config-reference/schema-field#multiple-schemas-and-client-side-schema

Please note that `schema` can take an array of schema file paths or URLs.

Let us know if you need any guidance migrating from Apollo codegen.

Charly, from The Guild.

Comment: Thank you. I did just that - migrated to GrapQL Code Generator. If someone else is reading this, I basically just copied the solution (code, settings etc) found in some random public project. https://github.com/UrsaMaritimus/orca/blob/main/libs/graphql/README.md